# Documentation: moved an example - the topic is now bugged/unavailable

Tags: bug, documentation

If you look at the current CUDA tag in Documentation, there are two topics:

[image: CUDA tag with 2 Topics in Documentation]

Seeing the 'hello, world!' as an example of introduction to CUDA I tried to move the only example within "Hello, world!" into the other topic. I got a warning that if I do so, the "Hello, world!" would contain no more examples and would be removed. I accepted that.

Now, it seems the action was not performed completely. Maybe it needs someone's approval? However, when I click on the "Hello, world!" I am directed an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page.

[image: Oops page]

Comment: Same happened in the [pygame documentation tag](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/topics)

Comment: IMO it seems that only the person who moved the example gets the error message …

Comment: Can you try again now? This might have been fixed by recent tweaks - I can't make it repro, certainly.