# Discarded attempt to move an example now results in an error

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-examples

Probably related to [Documentation: moved an example - the topic is now bugged/unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330192/documentation-moved-an-example-the-topic-is-now-bugged-unavailable).

I edited in a synopsis to [Running repair on Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cassandra/6556/running-repair-on-cassandra/22433/running-repair-on-cassandra), and then I realised there's already a similar topic with better examples: [Examples for running nodetool repaid](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cassandra/4873/repairs-in-cassandra/17193/examples-for-running-nodetool-repair), so amended my draft to move the exmaple there, deleting that topic. I continued to edit the draft, so that I could copy my changes to synopsis to the other topic.

However, then I realised this rendered the draft's text-areas unclickable, preventing me from easily copying the changes. I discarded the draft to get the original changes *and then do the whole thing again*. However, now I just get an error, for **both topics**! :(

Fortunately, both links work in incognito, so hopefully it's something specific to my account and the edits I tried.

Update: My earlier edit has since been approved, I can now access the first topic, but the second topic is still inaccessible.